# Eclipse-rcp: Create new Project loaded deleted Project with same name in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, project, new-project

Given scenario:
In the Project Explorer of Eclipse-RCP a user deleted (right mousclick->delete) a project with the name "XXX" from the workspace but he did not delete the project contents from his disk.
(So, the project exists on his disk physically. This use case is desired.)

Next time the user wants to create a new (blank) project with the same name "XXX" as the deleted project has had.

The problem:
When creating the new project, Eclipse realized that a project exists in this Workspace physically. So Eclipse "will automatically configure the JRE and the Project layout based on the existing source". 
After finishing the Create-Process, there will be the project with the Name "XXX", but Eclipse loaded the content(classes, etc) of the already deleted project.

[Image: Create new Project with same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Yny.png)

Is there a mechanism in Eclipse-RCP to check (before creating the new project) if there is a old deleted Project with the same (wished) name?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import existing projects from your workspace or project root.

`File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

It is possible to hide existing projects and search recusive through the directory stucture.

Comment: I don´t want to import an existing project.
In the process of creating a new Project, Eclipse should recognize the deleted project with the same Name in the workspace directory.